# FUSE - Camel visual designer plugin for eclipse clears routes on Saving

Tags: eclipse-plugin, apache-camel, redhat, jbossfuse, jboss-tools

I have installed Jboss Integration stack fuse camel editor and created a sample camel route,

```
<camelContext trace="false" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
<route/>
```

Now when I add and endpoint or any node through source/design view as,

```
<camelContext trace="false" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
<route>
    <from uri=""/>
</route>
```

**And save with `Ctrl+S` the routes and nodes are cleared. And empty camel context is left out.** Is this a bug or anyway of getting around it?

Please suggest some tips to get around or any other good tools to work with Camel for Visual tooling

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

This is a known issue which is caused by the try to save an invalid route. Please see [FUSETOOLS-1085](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/FUSETOOLS-1085) to follow the issue. The problem is that we consider a route with only an input as invalid atm. Therefore it is not saved. But don't worry, that will be fixed soon. Meanwhile you can work around that by simply always connecting nodes. That means in your case you should just add another node and connect both.

I am sorry for the inconvenience.

Lars